# Why isn't PHP PDO protecting my query from injection?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I'm still in the progress of learning PDO fully, but I was kind of surprised when I checked this evening if it worked to SQL Inject the URL parameter, and to my surprise, it did work. So I started thinking; the posted values are supposed to be sanitized automatically using PDO - prepared statements, which means there must be something wrong with my SQL query, am I right?

I'm having a page that needs a GET variable in order to gather corresponding data from my database with that ID. I have created a function that includes preparing the query, and as well as executing it to simplify the coding process. The code I have written now looks like:

```
 $request = $_GET['movie'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `url` = '$request'";
 $db = new database;
 $db->setDBC();

 $process = $db->executeQuery($sql);
 $cmd = $process->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

 $title = $cmd[1];
```

And the PDO Exception I get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''21-31282 ''' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\filmvote\include\databaseClass.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\filmvote\include\databaseClass.php(33): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\filmvote\recension.php(9): databaseManagement->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\filmvote\include\databaseClass.php on line 33

You get this kind of error when adding `' or 1-1` to the URL. What can I do about this? Really grateful for help.

Comment: That is not a prepared statement

Answer (score 13):

> the posted values are supposed to be sanitized automatically using PDO

Nope. Only if you use actual prepared statements like so:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE `url` = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['movie'])))  // <-- This sanitizes the value
  { 
    // do stuff
  }
```

will your the values you insert be automatically sanitized, and your query protected from SQL injection.

Otherwise, your SQL query will be executed like any old `mysql_query()`, and is vulnerable. PDO can not take a query and then automatically sanitize the vulnerable parts. That's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try prepared statements:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE url = ?");
$query->execute(array($request));
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```